# showing image title on top of image in Wordpress post

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

Curious to see if there is a method to display the title of an image on top of the image (ex. absolute positioned)? I am not in control of the image size/placement as it is done through the Wordpress admin panel. Can't find any understandable source material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The easiest way to edit your CSS file is to visit Appearance → Editor from your WordPress dashboard. You’ll want to open the style.css file (which should be open by default). This is your stylesheet."

Source https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/how-to-customize-a-wordpress-theme/

Comment: ? looking for a method that doesn't need to be hardcoded since I wont be the one inserting images

Comment: why not code is so it targets the img, regardless of who puts it in?  It's talking about CSS, not inline css.  This article also had the idea of changing the current display settings and therefore giving the user the ability to choose it.  https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/make-your-images-pop-with-super-easy-and-sexy-css-styling/